# jquery like function get element

Tags: javascript, function, chaining

I want to build a library, that is similiar to jquery

example of calling the function

```
$('#myDiv');
$('#myDiv').hide();
```

I am using a template from [here](http://www.codephun.com/how-to-create-a-simple-javascript-library-like-jquery/)

```
            (function () {
            var Q = function (params) {
                return new Library(params);
            };
            var Library = function (params) {
                var selector = document.querySelectorAll(params),
                    i = 0;
                this.length = selector.length;
                for (; i < this.length; i++) {
                    this[i] = selector[i];
                }
                return this;       
            };
            Q.fn = Library.prototype =
            {
                hide: function () {
                    var len = this.length;
                    while (len--) {
                        this[len].style.display = 'none';
                    }
                    return this;
                },
                show: function () {
                    var len = this.length;
                    while (len--) {
                        this[len].style.display = 'block';
                    }

                    return this;
                }   
            };
            if(!window.Q) {
                window.Q = Q;
            }
        })();
```

It works perfectly **But** if I want to get an HTML-Element by selector I have to call

```
$('#myDiv')[0] // Returns the element
```

instead of calling

```
$('#myDiv') // Returns an object
```

How can I get my element without the annoying '[0]' by default?

Comment: Instead of `return Object;`, try `return Object[0];`

Comment: Why not just write var $ = function(x){return document.getElementbyId(x);//return helper functions along with this as an object};

Comment: @Aravind how would I return the functions along with this as an object??

Comment: Related article on the subject about writing jQuery like thing: http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery

Answer (score 2):

I admit it was a bit of a challenge for me, though I had said it casually in the comment.

**Things to ponder:**
You want **$** to return an object that has both a value and some helper functions.
It sucks to have to write `new $()` to create an object, so I abstracted the object creation into the $ function, so that the $ function will take an id, and create an object with two things: a value which equals the document.getElementByID() object, and some helper functions.

Here you go:

```
var $ = function(x){
    var helpers = { /* write your helper functions here, remember this.value is the DOM object*/
    setColor: function(col){
   (this.value).setAttribute("color",col);     
}};
    function f(x){ this.value = document.getElementById(x);};
    f.prototype = helpers;
    return new f(x);
};

$('q').setColor("red");
```